# How to enable DHCP Cisco router

Tags: cisco, router, dhcp, cisco-commands, gns3

This is what I have done in my GNS3

[image]

- R3 - Router
- R4 - Switch

I have installed GNS3 and trying to enable on Router as mentioned above depict.

How to enabled ***DHCP*** on Cisco router R3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move to configuration mode by typing this (you exclude address that you don't want the DHCP to assign to any device, e.g. printers, static
IP addresses, etc.):

```
Router# config t
Router(conf)# ip dhcp excluded-adress <excluded address list>
```

Now you have to set up a pool, a pool of IP addresses:

```
Router(conf-dhcp)# ip dhcp pool <pool name>
```

now remember the pool is all possible host of the network addresses that you will assign here:

```
Router(conf-dhcp)# network <network> <mask or /length>
```

now you set up the default gateway (which in this case is itself):

```
Router(conf-dhcp)# default-router <gateway address>
```

The line above excludes the default gateway's IP address from the pool.

Setting up DNS server's IP address to exclude that too:

```
Router(conf-dhcp)# dns-server <DNS server list>
```

Now if you want to check DHCP clients, simply type:

```
Router(conf-dhcp)# ip dhcp binding
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what you asked for: `service dhcp`

What you probably wanted:
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/ip/configuration/guide/fipr_c/1cfdhcp.html

The trick is that the pool has to be in the same network as assigned to an interface.

Answer (score 1):

configuration for dhcp from cisco router:

```
 Router(config)# service dhcp

 Router(config)# ip dhcp excluded-address low-address [high-address]  
 Router(config)# ip dhcp pool name 
 Router(config)# no ip dhcp conflict logging 

Router(dhcp-config)# network network-number [mask | /prefix-length]

Router(dhcp-config)# domain-name domain
```